# gitlab-runner download and store cache file in each job of pipeline

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using Distributed caching(S3) for gitlab runner. It working fine but it downloads and store the cache file in s3 before and after each job execution. I want that it should download the cache file only once in a pipeline execution. otherwise the cache is burden and not improving the time of execution.

I am defining the global caching in gitlab-ci file

```
cache:
  key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
  untracked: true
  paths:
    - .m2/repository/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure how the cache should be handled individually for each job.

This will *prevent GitLab from downloading* the cache for this job.

```
no-cache:
    stage: no-cache
    cache: {}  
    ...
```

This will make GitLab *only pull* the cache for this job.

```
pull-cache:
    stage: pull-cache
    cache: 
        policy: pull  
    ...
```

This will make GitLab *only push* the cache for this job.

```
pull-cache:
    stage: pull-cache
    cache: 
        policy: push  
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, This can be a alternate way, but if I want to use cache then have to pull for each job.

Comment: Ah ok I get what you mean. So if you need the cache in every stage it'll be downloaded in every stage as well. But still you can at least reduce the execution time a bit with the `pull` policy if the cache is only read from and not changed by a job.